# How to pass command line arguments to python function inside python shell

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Please bear with me as my question is kinda two-fold. But I'll be very clear.

I have written a `python` script which I intend to be able to install using `pip install <package_name>`.

Let's say inside this folder I have following structure

```
<package_name>
    __init__.py
    area.py
```

I have a function `area_of_triangle` inside `area.py` that accepts command line arguments and computes the area of a triangle.

Below is the content of `area.py`

```
import argparse
from math import sqrt

def area_of_triangle():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="Area of Triangle")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", type=int, help="turn verbosity ON/OFF", choices=[0,1])
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--sideA", type=float, help="side A of triangle")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--sideB", type=float, help="side B of triangle")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--sideC", type=float, help="side C of triangle")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    s = (args.sideA + args.sideB + args.sideC)/2
    area_hero = sqrt(s*(s-args.sideA)*(s-args.sideB)*(s-args.sideC))

    if args.verbose==1:
        print("for triangle of sides {:<6f}, {:<6f}, {:<6f}, ".format(args.sideA, args.sideB, args.sideC))
        print("the semi perimeter is {:<6f} while the area is {:<6f}".format(s, area_hero))
    else:
        print("area = {:<6f}".format(area_hero))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    area_of_triangle()
```

I can fire up `cmd.exe` inside `package_name` directory and do `python area.py -a 5 -b 7 -c 10` and I would get the value of the area.

What I want to ask now is this: If inside of that open `cmd.exe` I now type `python` to enter into the python shell proper, is there anyway I can still pass those arguments to the function?
In essence, what I would like to be able to do is

```
from package_name import area_of_triangle
area_of_triangle() -a 5 -b 7 -c 10
```

I have tried this and found that it won't work. So is there any way of accomplishing something equivalent?

I expect the answer is NO. In that case (perhaps I should as this in a separate question, but I just want to give a good enough context) how do I add `package_name` to `path` during `pip install package_name` so that the user can just go ahead and run `area_of_triangle() -a 5 -b 7 -c 10`. I want to be able to accomplish something like `mkvirtualenv envname`

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You want to pass a, b, and c as function arguments.  Consider `def f(x=None): return x`.  You can *call* the function as `> f(5)`.  This said, you should go and run through a few tutorials online and see all the possibilities for yourself.

Comment: Typically all of the argparse stuff would happen in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, ending with a call to the function with the passed arguments. If you do it that way, then you'll be able to manually pass the args to the function just like any other.

Comment: The `argparse` unittest code tests both ways - modifying the `sys.argv[1:]` list, and providing an explicit `argv` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments as a parameter to function (a list)

```
def area_of_triangle(arguments):
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
    ...
```

And then pass `sys.args` to the function.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    area_of_triangle(sys.args[1:])
```

This way you can always call your function with the list of arguments:

```
area_of_triangle(["-a", "5", "-b", "7", "-c", "10"])
```

But the proper way to go is to adhere to single responsibility principle. Make your `area_of_triangle` function do only what it says on a tin: calculate area of triangle. Make it accept 3 arguments for triangle sides and move parameter parsing to different function.

Then your code will be something like this:

```
def area_of_triangle(a,b,c):
    ...

def parse_parameters(arguments):
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
    return (args.sideA, args.sideB, args.sideC)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a,b,c = parse_parameters(sys.args[1:])
    area_of_triangle(a,b,c)
```

This way you will be able to test parameter parsing and area calculation independently.

Comment: `parse_args` uses `sys.argv[1:]` in the default case.  `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, which `parse_args` uses as the `prog` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks great. But I'm still thinking about it for the case where there are optional arguments like verbosity. The way it is now, I don't know how to include optional arguments except to include it as a named argument or have the function caller supply a value for it every time (which defeats the purpose of it bein optional). But if I have to use named arguments then my function becomes kinda clunky

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty but works:

```
import sys

from package_name import area_of_triangle

sys.argv = 'x -a 5 -b 7 -c 10'.split()
area_of_triangle()
```

Output:

```
area = 16.248077
```

All command line arguments are in `sys.argv`. The first one is the file name. I replaced by the dummy `x`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I account for optional arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by optional arguments? Just supply the string as you would on the command line.